# Get specific data from a string? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, concatenation

I have a string named group.

```
string group="|17|11|";
```

So my issue is that I want my output to be something like this:

17
11

so these 2 numbers should be stored in the database as two records. and another case if the

```
 string group = "|17|11|05|";
```

it will store 3 values in the database. The number of groups always differs in different strings it can be 1 or many.

17
11
05

the database structure is like this:
`id, group`

Thanks. Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Comment: Is this to be done in the database?  in a stored procedure?  In application code outside the database?

Comment: This question is so confusing. Where is the input coming from? What "database structure"? You've given us two column names. Are you asking for an SQL solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!

Thank your comments and suggestions..I'll improve the way I question.. HAHAH
I hope you guys and gals get the logic. Quite simple :)

```
        string group = "|17|11|05|";
        string[] words = group.Split('|');
        foreach (string word in words) {
            if (word.ToString() != "") {
                string cg = word;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You know you don't need to keep calling `ToString` on `word`? It's already a string...

Answer (score 0):

Since the language isn't specified, I'll throw out the first idea that comes to my head.

In .Net, you'd use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Odds are, the language you're using has something similar.